# What is the correct distribution of reading time for short text

Tags: normal-distribution, modeling

A mobile app I am creating shows a sequence of headlines which when tapped on shows more detailed information. The detailed information can belong to one of several, but small, categories and has a very standard format (visual layout, content parts etc) and the same context (shopping).  I want to be to do the following

- monitor the reading times for the detailed information
- filter out outliers in the form of the user accidentally tapping the wrong headline and exiting or tapping a headline and being called away and then appearing to be spending "too much time" reading the information.

I have currently implemented all of this by keeping track of the number of views in each category, the running mean viewing time and the standard deviation.  I account for differences in the length of the text being read by normalizing the viewing time for 100 words.

The length of the information to be read is short - always less than 140 characters.

However, having now implemented all of this I have started to wonder if I have any valid reasons to believe that reading times will be normally distributed.  This [stats.stackexchange thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/15033/whats-the-correct-distribution-for-page-reading-time) suggests that the logarithm of the normalized reading time will be normally distributed.

However, the underlying data on which that conclusion is based is for web pages which typically will have far more than 140 characters of text.  In my own context here is there

- any research suggesting that reading times might follow a different distribution?
- any reason to believe that the conclusions in that article will also apply to short snippets of text?

Comment: The log-normal distribution seems like a reasonable assumption, but this is a blind guess. If you can include a sample of your data, you are more likely to receive an informed response.

Comment: Yes, I too wish I had data on which to base all of this.  Given that the app is only just being launched I do not have such data. I have Googled for tweet length vs read time stats but not yet found anything useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of a "correct" distribution is a tricky one, even if you had data. Without data, this is speculative at best.

The normal distribution may not be ideal, since it doesn't take into account the positive nature of reading times. The log-normal assumption will take this into account, and is somewhat more flexible (right skewed, but can be approximately normal for certain parameter combinations).

It seems (to me at least) that the Log-normal assumption is a better default option, with an easy implementation. You can update your algorithm as necessary when more data becomes available.